# How to secure notes or notebooks in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

There are times that I will leave my computer open together with the Evernote and because there are certain notes that is private or I don't want to be shared some people can easily see it.

**Question:**

I would like my notes or even a notebooks to be private, is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

Unfortunately there are no way that we can set a password to a certain note or even notebook.

**Suggestion:**

Luckily we can encrypt certain text inside the note, you can do this by

1. Select the text that you want to be encrypted
2. Right click on it
3. Choose `Encrypt Selected Text`
4. Type the pass phrase.

**Note:**

If you forgot the pass phrase then there is no way that you can recover the text that you encrypted. Evernote doesn't store the pass phrase.